# How is someone supposed to find this site from another SE site?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, meta

I looked for a link on a different SE site (Super User) and its Meta, but didn't find it. I had to search the web. Is there a link I missed?

**Note**: I found this site via a web search. But I would expect a link somewhere on all of these sites.

Comment: Well, how did *you*?

Comment: In which case, how did you know what to search for?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I've been on this network (mainly SO) for a while, and have ran into this in the past. I don't remember where. Perhaps a discussion on a site-meta whether a question should be there or here.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I searched for meta stackexchange.

Answer (score 9):

Most people are not supposed to find this site - they are expected to post on the child meta of the site they are on.

Most users do not need to know about the larger network and going through their site-specific meta should be enough.

Comment: Ah, if only that were true. I reported a couple of bugs in the search index on Web Apps' Meta, and there hasn't been a whiff of anyone from the development team.

Comment: @ale - which doesn't mean we didn't see it.

Comment: I can't really downvote this answer because as a diamond bearer, your answer is, in a way, the official (and therefore correct) answer. I do, however, agree with the sentiment in [ale's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295460/how-is-someone-supposed-to-find-this-site-from-another-se-site#comment958584_295462).

Comment: @ispiro - false. Just 'cause I have a diamond, doesn't mean you can't d/v.

Comment: I suppose, but without a comment, tag change, or whatever there's no way to know. I know you want people to report things on their "home" meta rather than running here, but if they do and it seems to just get lost in the ether, they'll be frustrated. Anyway, this is hashed out elsewhere and has nothing to do with the original question, so I'll just drop it.

Comment: @ale Odds are you'd get exactly the same response posting the question here as you would on a child meta.  Someone is likely to see the post in either case, and not respond to it in either case.  And of course regardless of that fact, that you posted *one* post and anecdotally *suspect* it wasn't seen doesn't indicate any larger pattern.  If you just look at [bug tags here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) you'll see most are unanswered by an SE employee, just as would be the case on a child meta.

Comment: @ispiro As I understand it, posting a [feature-request] or [bug] on any meta automatically puts it in front of the Staff via their internal ticket system, whether it's a child meta or this one. (The other two ([discussion] and [support]) are typically site-specific and should be on a child meta, as they generally don't need Staff and do need local users and moderators.)

Comment: Not to hijack your answer, but **if** this site is NOT for "*Most people*", and also NOT for "*Most users*", **then** who or what is the target audience of this site? And where in the SE-universe is there any explanation about it?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens - it is for people who are interested in the whole network, those who look for it...

Comment: @ale: I have personally had SE staff slap [status-whatever] tags on posts made on child metas. Not MSO, either. So I can attest that the system *does* work.

Comment: @pierre you're right,  and behavior here is the root of behavior on all site's meta (more or less for historical reasons when this site was meta.so _also_ )

Answer (score 9):

If you really want to find this site, you need to open the network dropdown:

[image]

And type "meta" in the search bar:

[image]

That simple!

Answer (score 7):

It's the first site listed under "Other" in the footer.

Specific posts are also frequently linked in the side bar. (*"Featured on Meta"*)

Comment: Thanks. I would absolutely not look for it there. Notice that it's the only "Meta" site there. +1 nevertheless.

Answer (score 4):

There's also a link on the `stackexchange.com` domain:

[image]

And in the site dropdown on the top left (right on SO):

[image]

Comment: I was 2 seconds earlier _cool sunglasses_ :D

Comment: But I included a second place B)